# google sheets, if function with checkbox

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, conditional-statements, vlookup

I am trying to add an if function to my vlookup.

current formula: `=vlookup("*treasury*",'January (1/22)'!B:E,4,false)`

I want to add another condition for it to check if the row that the information exist on is check marked (column "J" in this example).  If so, then display the vlookup.

My column "J" has checkboxes.

Comment: your vlookup is not used in correct way. can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/26cy2zw here is a pic. this help?

Comment: can you recreate your scenario here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YBCE9ReJYrqicU8t8tzFdmxZZ3ESiVl1BgvFbT2wtKg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Okay. should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(FILTER(Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!J2:J=TRUE, REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!B2:B, "(?i)treasury")))
```

Comment: works awesome! very helpful. thank you!